# T_OBJECT_OPERATOR - Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8

this is the php code:

```
<?php
$tid = $job_node->field_job_cv_destination['und'][0]['tid'];
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$name = $term->name;
?>
```

and that is the error:

```
ParseError: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in -
```

rules_php_eval() (line 2 -/web/maavarim/sites/all/modules/contrib/rules/modules/php.eval.inc(125) : eval()'d code)

can anyonw know what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement your code as below

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (isset($vars['node']) && in_array($vars['node']->type, array('article', 'column'))) {
    // Set header to topic for articles and columns
    // @TODO: consider primary topic field (no multiselect), default to below if empty
    $term = taxonomy_term_load($vars['node']->field_topic_ref[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid']);
    $vars['head_title'] = $term->name;
  }
  else {
    $vars['head_title'] = $vars['title'];
  }
}
```